# Criteria for transaction order by ordering service in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a question regarding the order of transactions done by the ordering service in Hyperledger Fabric.

1. Are there any criteria to determine the order of transactions in a block e.g timestamp ?
2. What happens if 2 transactions executed in parallel arrive at the same time? Which one will be put first in the block?

Regarding the second question, let's say that there are only 2  transactions that will arrive first on endorsers who will create the transaction proposals(including the write sets) and then the client sdk will send these transaction proposals to the ordering service. So the ordering service will receive two transaction proposals with the same write sets. How does the ordering service determine the order of these transactions?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/efdf68767d03c884b12ba68dcad93d7dbbab689a/orderer/consensus/solo/consensus.go#L111) is the beginning of the order transaction process. I choose the solo orderer to keep it simple.

When the orderer received a transaction, it just appends the transaction into the block until it meets one of the conditions (batchtimeout, batchsize, maxbytes,[...here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/efdf68767d03c884b12ba68dcad93d7dbbab689a/orderer/common/blockcutter/blockcutter.go#L69)), the block will be cut. This means which message comes first, it will be put first.

The orderer won't care about the content of the transactions. Its mission is just appending the transaction as fast as possible :)